# Spy Number using Recursion

Tags: python, recursive-datastructures

```
def spynum (n,r,sm=0,pd=1):

 #s = 0

 #p = 1

 #b = False 

 if n == 0:

  print (sm==pd)

  return sm == pd

 else:

  rem = n % 10

  sm += rem

  pd *= rem

  print (sm,pd,rem)

  spynum(n//10,rem,sm,pd)

num = 1124

print (spynum(num,num%10,0,1))
```

The program returns Boolean also working if I print the variable inside base condition but it is not print the same outside the function.Im really confused ABT it !

Comment: You are calling `spynum` from inside `spynum` from inside `spynum` ... and so on.  At some point the last invocation finds that n == 0 and returns a boolean.  That boolean is returned to the invocation before it, which simply ignores it, not to the main program.  You need to propagate the answer back through your chain of `spynum` invocations, all the way to the top and the main program.  It's probably just a one-word change: add `return ` before the recursive invocation of `spynum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def spynum (n,r,sm=0,pd=1):
 #s = 0
 #p = 1
 #b = False 
 if n == 0:
  print (sm==pd)
  return sm == pd <-- returns either true or false
 else:
  rem = n % 10
  sm += rem
  pd *= rem
  print (sm,pd,rem)
  spynum(n//10,rem,sm,pd)
num = 1124
print (spynum(num,num%10,0,1))
```

The `==` operator compares and returns either a `true` or `false` value. To return a number, consider returning an `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions; they return to their immediate caller, and if you don't return a value on some path, they return `None`.

You need to return the recursive result:

```
def spynum (n, r, sm=0, pd=1):
    if n == 0:
        print (sm == pd)
        return sm == pd
    else:
        rem = n % 10
        sm += rem
        pd *= rem
        print (sm, pd, rem)
        return spynum(n//10, rem, sm, pd)
```